# Display div over video (iframe or object)

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a website where the header and footer are in `fixed` position, while the middle content can be scrollable. In fact, when we scroll the content should go under the header or footer, because the website takes 100% height and I chose to apply `overflow: auto;` to the body. It's not possible to have a specific height for the middle content, 'cause header and footer are fixed sizes.

I applyed `z-index` to all elements, and it works great but I need to embed videos from Youtube, Vimeo or other... Ordinary, these videos are displayed using `iframe` or `object` ; my client puts directly the embed code in the backoffice. Here is my problem : when I scoll, the videos are displayed over header and footer even if I set a specific `z-index` ; other elements in middle content are well hidden...

Do you have an idea to solve this problem ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to set wmode to transparent in your flash. so in your embed / object code add `wmode="transparent"`

or

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
```

Comment: The thing is : I can't force my client to manually add this code inside the embed code. Do you think it can work if I add it with Javascript after loading ?

Comment: yep, you can write the property on load (added it as an answer)

Comment: Hmmm.. I dont think you can, since it gets its parameters as soon as you create it... You could maybe detect a flash movie, strip it  (So get file name, params, and width / height and reconstruct it with mode transparent...

Comment: that would be a shame, but I know it at least works with youtube!

Answer (score 6):

Without using jquery you can simple use this in your 'iframe' tag

`src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/yourVideo?wmode=transparent"`

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Hans' answer:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('iframe').each(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr("src");
        $(this).attr("src",url+"?wmode=transparent");
    });
});
```

(you still have to use z-index)

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Yisela's answer:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('iframe').each(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr("src");
        $(this).attr("src",url+"?wmode=transparent");
    });
});
```